# Which format to display the gsmap downloaded data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, precipitation, data-source

Where can I download gsmap data especially for precipitation / rainfall and which format can be supported by QGIS software?

Comment: Welcome to the GIS SE. I see you are a new user, please could you have a look at the Tour link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour. It will help you understand how the GIS SE Question and answer Site works. Could you please provide us with some more information, GSMap data, could you expand on what you mean? Where are you looking for precipitation for? Rwanda? The more information you provide the better people can assist. I have a feeling this question may be suited to another data request SE site.

Comment: If you refer to JAXA Realtime Rainfall Watch they mention an ftp server: "To use data, user registration is needed. If you have already registered as user of the GSMaP_NRT (JAXA Global Rainfall Watch), you can download GSMaP_NOW data from the same ftp server." Have you tried this?

Comment: Thank you Keagan! Actually I am in Rwanda, But i want to download the precipitation data so that i can use them in my studies. Thank you

Comment: QGIS supports most formats; that's one of the advantages of this program over other GIS software. See the user manual for a list of supported data types: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html